# Simple reducer combining generating issues

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I ran to a issue while trying to code with redux.
I basically am trying to combine reducers.I followed through 
[Getting Started with Redux tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-reducer-composition-with-combinereducers#/tab-transcript) but i seem to have an issue that is totally different. I could not find an solution, though i understand the error.

The following is my reducers i want to combine:

```
const increment = (state = 0, action)=>{
    console.log(state,action)
    switch (action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state-1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
const decrement = (state = 0, action)=>{
    console.log(state,action)
    switch (action.type){
        case 'DECEREMNT':
            return state-1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
const combineReducers = require('redux').combineReducers;

const counter = combineReducers({
    increment,
    decrement,
})

module.exports = counter;
```

If i do the following it works without an issue,

```
const counter = (state = 0, action)=>{
    console.log(state,action)
    switch (action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return state+1;
        case 'DECEREMNT':
            return state-1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
module.exports = counter
```

So i believe i have some issue while combining reducers.
The following is the error i received:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {increment, decrement}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Counter`.
```

Here is my index if it is relevant:

```
"use strict";

const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const createStore = require("redux").createStore

var counter = require("./reducers")

const store = createStore(counter)
console.log("First call",store.getState()) 

const Counter = ({ 
    value,
    increment, 
    decrement
}) =>(
    <div>
        <h1>{value}</h1>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    </div>
);
const render = () =>{
    console.log("value ",store.getState());
    console.log("dispatch action",)
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Counter value={store.getState()}
      increment={()=>{store.dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'})}}
      decrement={()=>{store.dispatch({type:'DECREMENT'})}}/>,
      document.getElementById('content')
    );
}
store.subscribe(render)
render()
```

I am trying to learn to separate reducers. I have done few projects already but i had a reducer file too big causing merge issues. Let me know if i am doing the correct approach and any suggestion to fix the above issue will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I tried to call store.dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'}) independently, it does works but causes browser to keep increment the values causing the browser to freeze.

The Following react code is working .

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        console.log(this.props.value)
        return <div>
                {this.props.value.counter}
                <button onClick={this.props.increment}>+</button>
                <button onClick={this.props.decrement}>-</button>
            </div>
    }
});

const render = () =>{
    console.log("value ",store.getState());
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Counter value={store.getState()}
      increment={()=>{store.dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'})}}
      decrement={()=>{store.dispatch({type:'DECREMENT'})}}/>,
      document.getElementById('content')
    );
}
store.subscribe(render)
render()
```

with reducers from [redux page](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html)

Comment: You are creating reducers when you should be creating actions. Your reducer should be `counter` your actions should be `increment` and `decrement`

Comment: I still could not figure out the cause . So i changed the code to use react.create class and it seems to work now. This is really confusing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of your app needs to be a number that represents the counter's value.

The version of the reducer that works, works because it's a single reducer that produces a single number -- that is the expected state.

The `combineReducers` version doesn't work because `combineReducers` produces a composition of reducers in the form of an object. In your case, this object has two properties -- `increment` and `decrement`, each managed by the respective reducer. This produces an application state of this shape

```
{ increment: 0, decrement: 0 }
```

instead of a single number. Totally not what you want. Btw, this is exactly why you're getting the aforementioned exception, it's originating at

```
<Counter value={store.getState()}
```

when the `value` prop is being bound to the object instead of a number.

The bottom line is, you want to stick with the original version of the reducer, OR if you want to refactor it, extract the increment/decrement code into their own functions, but call them from within the respective `switch` cases in the reducer.

Comment: Thanks for this lucid explanation. Now i understand how to properly use use  and how to actually combine reducers. Thanks a lot.